# Cookies will not set

Tags: php

```
 setcookie("test","sonali",time()+3600,"../php/"," ",false,false); 
 echo $_COOKIE["test"];
```

> Notice:Undefined index:test in
>   D:\projects\Trainee2014\Sonali\php\cookiedemo.php on line 3

if possible please give me solution

Comment: $_COOKIE['test'] will have a value if you request the page in the php folder ..

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 setcookie("test","sonali",time()+3600,"../php/"," ",false,false); 
 $check = $_COOKIE["test"];

 if (isset($check)){
    echo 'Cookie not set';
 }
 else{
    echo 'Cookie set';
 }

?>
```

Try the above code to handle the notice.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this and try,

```
setcookie("test","sonali",time()+3600,"../php/"," ",false,false);
 echo isset($_COOKIE["test"]) ? $_COOKIE["test"] : '';
```

Problem is at the first time `$_COO KIE["test"]` is not set. so you need to refresh. in order to avoid this problem you should simply use the if condition with isset().

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Syntax  `setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure);`

Use like this in page :

```
<?php
$value = "cookie value";

// send a simple cookie
    setcookie("user",$value);
OR 

// send a cookie that expires in 24 hours
setcookie("user",$value, time()+3600*24);
?>
```

Access it on page like this :

```
<?php

echo $_COOKIE["user"];
       OR
echo $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["user"];


// Print all cookies
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
setcookie("test","sonali",time()+3600,"../php/",false,false); 
print_r($_COOKIE);
echo $_COOKIE["test"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set setcookes function only 5 parameter

> setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain);

Answer (score 0):

The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/php/', the cookie will only be available within the /php/ directory and all sub-directories such as /php/../ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

Ref: http://php.net/setcookie

```
setcookie("test","sonali",time()+3600,"/"," ",false,false); 
echo $_COOKIE["test"];
```